# Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_register_plugin_realpath()

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I'm having an issue on an old site. This happened at random, and did not follow an upgrae or edit. I've followed the steps outlined in previous questions, including :

1. Renaming the plugins and adding them back in one by one to see if it fixes the issue.
2. Uploading a new plugins.php file from Wordpress' current build
3. Uploading a new settings.php file from Wordpress' current build

None of these things have fixed the issue...I only get more warnings. Any other ideas?

http://hoosierpma.com/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're core version of WordPress is 3.9.0 or greater as the function was added then: [docs on wp_register_plugin_realpath()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_plugin_realpath/)

If you're on 3.9+, considering that modifying the plugins directory and core files had no impact there's a good chance code in the theme could be messing you up. Try changing to one of the default themes (twenty-fourteen for example) and see if you get the error. Also [enable debugging mode in wp-config.php](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) to see if you can get any more info on the error with the following command:

`define('WP_DEBUG', true);`